# What do the following Windows Registry string values mean?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu, regedit, string

While editing the Registry, in particular to tweak Windows Explorer's right-click/context menu, I've come across the following values:

```
NoWorkingDirectory
OnlyInBrowserWindow
LaunchExplorerFlags
```

Because these more advanced intricacies of the Windows Registry are so [badly](https://superuser.com/questions/1183842/in-the-windows-registry-what-is-the-legacydisable-string-value-and-what-exact) [documented](https://superuser.com/questions/1243140/in-the-windows-registry-what-is-the-programmaticaccessonly-string-value-and-how) by MS, and because my own Googling of each of these strings brought nothing up, I'm left wondering:

1. What each of these string values does.
2. All the possible data values for each string value.

It seems strange to me that after so many years of the Windows Registry being prised apart and tinkered with by Windows power users, there's absolutely no-one out there that has either come to know the meaning of these string values, which is why I'm banking on the fact that someone somewhere does *or* is able to find out.

Comment: The NoWorkingDirectory value lets you issue a command against a directory without adding that directory to the environmental variables path.

Comment: [What's the meaning of "NoWorkingDirectory" string value in Windows Registry?](//superuser.com/q/703275)

Comment: LaunchExplorerFlags see [All folders open in new windows](//superuser.com/a/993161)